# Identify Rio Bravo Opening Song name

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

What is the song name, in the opening of movie [*Rio Bravo*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSqloJazgR4)?
It is playing from beginning to 1:05.

Answer (score 1):

The score to the movie was written by Dimitri Tiomkin. There is a double CD of the soundtrack available from Amazon, but this piece is not on it. It probably wasn't memorable enough to be included.

Comment: This should be a comment since it doesn't answer the question...

Comment: @Bebs I only posted because I thought I had found the piece. it turned out I hadn't but I still consider the information that this is a nameless piece of underscoring useful (there's an upvote so someone else  thinks so too). Unless somebody has access to the studio's or Tiomkin's archive this is very probably the closest to an answer this question is ever going to get.